# jquery simple calculation script little help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i made this jquery script with help of friends.

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/Wu7k7/

jquery:

```
$('input[name=rdOptin]').click(function(){
var selected=$(this).val();
var var0 = 0.3;
var var1 = 20;
var var2 = var1 * 3.9 / 100;
var var3 = 20;
var var4 = (var1 + var3) * 3.9 / 100;
if (selected == 'norm'){
    $("#calc_value").html(var0 + var1 + var2);}
else {
    $("#calc_value").html(var0 + var1 + var3 + var4);}

});
```

html form

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="form1.php"> <b> Option 1:</b>
     <input type="radio" name="rdOptin" value="norm" checked="checked" />Normal
    <input type="radio" name="rdOptin" value="exp" />Expert
<br />
<b>Calculated Value:</b>
<div class="valueDisp">
    <div id="calc_value">
        select options
    </div>
</div>
```

1. i was trying to add a text element to output of the selection. For example say: on selecting "Expert" radio the output is "41.86" how can i make this output look like "Numbers 41.86".
2. on selecting "Normal" radio the output is "21.080000000000002" how can i fix it to "21.08"?

its rather tricky for me.

Please help friends.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: This question has already been asked several times. See [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. put "Numbers" inside `.html("Numbers "+yourNumber)` and use:
2. [toFixed()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp) before

shorter variant:

```
if (selected == 'norm')
    var total = var0 + var1 + var2;
else
    var total = var0 + var1 + var3 + var4;
$("#calc_value").html("Numbers "+total.toFixed(2));
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/Wu7k7/1/)**

Comment: thanks a lot friend. also, can i add css "style" formatting to "Numbers" i.e. to change the color, etc?

Comment: @user2057047 yep, just change to `html("<span style='color: red;'>Numbers</span> "+total.toFixed(2));` or set `class` instead of `style` attribute and use it in your css file

Comment: @user2057047 you're always wellcome

Comment: also one more thing. How can i add this style to variable? i,e, style to variable "total"

Comment: @user2057047 `html("<span style='color: red;'>Numbers</span> <span style='color: green;'>"+total.toFixed(2)+"</span>");` check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/Wu7k7/2/)

Comment: @user2057047 but using `class`es is better and don't `check` it before  if you you want user to do it: [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/Wu7k7/3/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34060/discussion-between-user2057047-and-vladkras)

Comment: freind i need one of your small help as well. can you come to the chat i requested?

Answer (score 3):

Use `.toFixed()` to convert the floating point number to a fixed precision decimal string.  Also, separate your calculation from the presentation, to avoid repetition:

```
var result;
if (selected == 'norm'){
    result = var0 + var1 + var2;
} else {
    result = var0 + var1 + var3 + var4;
}

$('#calc_value').text("Numbers " + result.toFixed(2));
```

Comment: @user2057047 no, I already fixed that (it's in the last line)

Comment: also, can i add css "style" formatting to "Numbers" i.e. to change the color, etc?

Comment: Just change the `.text` line to use `.html` instead again, and put a `<span style="foo">Numbers</span>` instead of what's there now.

Comment: okay i changed to .html. Now it looks like this. 
$('#calc_value').html("<span style="color:red;" + "Numbers " + "</span> + result.toFixed(2)); is it okay?

Answer (score 2):

First issue can be fixed by appending your number value to the text you want like so

```
var yourVal = 41.86;
var outputVal = "Numbers "+yourVal;
```

For the second issue use [`.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to use just two decimal places.

```
var yourVal = 21.08000000000002;
var outputVal = yourVal.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: can you please update the fiddle? i am not very much aware of programming. It wil be a great help friend. http://jsfiddle.net/Wu7k7/

Answer (score 1):

you need to use [.toFixed(2)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) to round here

```
$('input[name=rdOptin]').click(function(){
    var selected=$(this).val();
    var var0 = 0.3;
    var var1 = 20;
    var var2 = var1 * 3.9 / 100;
    var var3 = 20;

    var result;
    if (selected == 'norm'){
        result = var0 + var1 + var2;
    } else {
        var var4 = (var1 + var3) * 3.9 / 100;
        result = var0 + var1 + var3 + var4;
    }

    $("#calc_value").html('Numbers: ' + result.toFixed(2));

}).filter(':checked').click();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ddKNN/)

Comment: Hii. Thanks for answering. How can i add this style to variable? i,e, style to variable result